# What does "reflect on" means in this context?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

> Political parties engage strongly during a campaign. Popular votations
> are an opportunity to highlight themselves, **reflecting on** concrete
> issue against the background of their basic ideologies and programmes,
> and pointing out the presumed interests of their voters and their
> affinity to interest groups.
>
> *- Swiss democracy by Wolf Linder

"reflect on" has two meanings according to Cambridge Dictionary:
1 (as a phrase) - to influence people's opinion of a person, group, or organization
2 (reflect alone) - to think carefully

I don't know which meaning is right for this context? Or is there any other meaning?

Comment: It's rather odd English - maybe a bad translation from the German. (I didn't think _votation_ was even a word, but apparently it's a kind of referendum peculiar to Switzerland - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voting_in_Switzerland .) I think it's the second meaning of _reflect on_, because the first is usually in the form _reflect well/badly on_.

Comment: This is poorly translated English. It may be a literal translation of an idiom in the original language of the text.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about a translation error, not well-formed English and is impossible to answer without being able to read the original text.